# Delete the file before deleting the row data?

Tags: php, mysql, delete-file

I wanna delete the file from the uploads folder before deleting the row data from the database. I used the below code but its giving the error.
Error=> No such file or directory

```
function deleteItem($conn,$product_id)
{
    $stmtgetfile=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_item WHERE product_id=:product_id");
    $stmtgetfile->bindParam('product_id',$product_id);
    $stmtgetfile->execute();
    $row = $stmtgetfile->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $item=$row['product_photo'];
    $path="../uploads/".$item;
    unlink($path);
    // $stmtdelete=$conn->prepare("DELETE FROM tbl_item WHERE product_id=:product_id");
    // $stmtdelete->bindParam('product_id',$product_id);
    // if($stmtdelete->execute())
    //     return true;
    // return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get absolute path of root directory.

```
$path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/".$item;
if(file_exists($path)){
   unlink($path);
}else{
   echo $path; // check path here
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Your method helped me to get full path of the file thus finally it was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to fix the `$path` value to get actual path. You can use [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant for the same. And, also use [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function to check if the file actually exists or not, before trying to delete it. It seems that some of the file path(s) in your database are non-existent now.

```
$path = __DIR__ . "/../uploads/" . $item;
if (file_exists($path)) {
    unlink($path);
}
```

Also, if you are just going to need `product_photo` column value, don't use `Select *`. Change prepare query statement to:

```
$stmtgetfile=$conn->prepare("SELECT product_photo FROM tbl_item 
                             WHERE product_id=:product_id");
```

Do read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/2469308)

Comment: I tried your code. It removed the error but still the file is not deleted. And the file im trying is existing.

Comment: @SoonangRai What is the actual file path as per your OS? `echo $path` to check whether you are getting the same file path or not.

Comment: This is path where this code exist. -> C:\xampp\htdocs\boutiqueAdmin\app    And this is the path for file to be deleted. -> C:\xampp\htdocs\boutiqueAdmin\uploads